# external js click functions not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, google-chrome

Here's my head tag:

```
<head>
 <!-- link JS here -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src="../../template/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='../../template/js/preload.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='../../template/js/responsive-turnkey.js'></script>
</head>
```

simple eh? So the "responsive-turnkey.js" file is the one that has all the click functions that need to run once the user clicks the necessary DOM elements.

Here is the "responsive-turnkey.js" file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

alert("This alert works on page load");

$(".btn").click(function(){
alert("this alert works on .btn clicked");
});

});
```

The first alert works on page load, but when I click on the element with the class ".btn", the click function doesn't work and the alert does not sound. THIS ONLY WORKS IN FIREFOX.

Does NOT work in: chrome or safari

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that you indeed have a collection of elements with the class "btn" ready when the DOM is rendered?

Try console.log($(".btn")) to see if you indeed have elements.

Comment: What does the chrome console say?

Comment: Why people just don't use it this way? `$(".btn").on("click", function() { // blah });`

Comment: Yes I verified. Console logs the elements being there. 

@MelanciaUK I just tried that and it still did not work.

Comment: There's something else, somewhere else, that's probably messing up with it. Show more of your code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, I just figured since this simple code didnt work, there is no point in showing all my code. It's best to start with something small and get it working.

Comment: I'll put my html code in there if ya want

Comment: It could be something on the other scripts loaded before this one.

Comment: True, I will comment them out... give me a sec

Comment: So the element is an anchor... Try this way: `$(".btn").on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault; alert('blah'); });`

Comment: @MelanciaUK Okay so I commented out all the other scripts. all thats on the html page is that one external js file, and the button.
When I click on the btn, the click function is still not working.

Comment: But the first alert works just fine.... this is so annoying.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I did already try that way, look above in the code snippets i provided.

Comment: I've posted an answer with an example.

Comment: the "e.preventDefault();" is irrelevant in this situation.

Comment: No, because if you remove it, the thing stops working. And with it, it's working.

Comment: OKay my problem is... that the file works in FIREFOX ONLY. But doesnt work in CHROME or SAFARI. Your example is what I am using in the EXTERNAL file. The click function is still NOT firing on click.

Comment: I'm using Chrome here. And also checked on Internet Explorer 10. I don't have Firefox installed.

Comment: And JSfiddle is irrelevant too because it's not using external file...

Comment: Alright then. I just tried to help. Will delete the answer.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I put the js code in a <script> tag on the page and it works fine. Its just the fact that its external, and it's not firing like it should... but it works in FF...

Comment: @BryanCorey I found the solution!

Comment: So the console logs were showing the element was loading... that's because I had it in the wrong file to test... OOPS. So in reality, the elements were not on the page as @BryanCorey stated. I had to actually add the function $.getScript() to pull the script in after the elements loaded in a load function.

Comment: If you found the solution, please put it in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getScript("../../template/js/responsive-turnkey.js", function(){
    alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    });
```

I put this in my load function() to read the script in after elements loaded successfully.